# If Else condition in Jenkins Pipeline "read output from file"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

Jenkins Pipeline get output from a shell script/command and based on the if else condition run the downstream job

example:-

```
stage 'stage1' 
    node {
            build job: 'build_test'
}
```

I want the downstream job to be executed after checking if "git rev-parse  HEAD" and lastSuccessful log output is not the same.

for example in shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
set +x
JOB_NAME="build_test"
cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JOB_NAME
SuccVer=`cat /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/$JOB_NAME/lastSuccessful/log |grep -a Revision |awk '{print $4}'`
ver=`git rev-parse  HEAD`
if [ "$SuccVer" = "$ver" ]
        then 
    echo "Successful"
else 
        echo "not Successful"

fi
```

same required for groovy

Comment: Please be more specific about your query

Comment: Please provide the code with the problem you face and the error you get.